# How to replace a word in tab deliminated file from shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a lot of tabdeliminated files in a folder. I would like to read each of these, and replace first work with another word, and write it back in tab-delimited formate as well?
Can someone help me to do it in bash?

```
Control AAA
Q   B   C   D   E   F
0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0
```

I tried this on MAC and I get the following error:

```
 grep -rl 'Control' ./ | xargs sed -i 's/Control/CerbC9/g'
sed: 1: ".//C9_chr_binary.txt": invalid command code .
```

Thanks

Comment: I updated the OP

Comment: try `sed  's/^Control/CerbC9/' *`

Comment: It prints all the files, what I want is to does this replacement in each file and save it with the same filename.

Comment: just check whether the replacement was correct. If yes, then add `-i` parameter

Comment: Word is in the first line of the file, and my files are huge. Can you specify only look at the first line? Also -i didn't work

Comment: just take one file for checking purpose, `sed -i 's/^[\t ]*Control/CerbC9/' first_file`. then check whether the replacement happens or not

Comment: Please try: `grep -rl 'Control' ./ | xargs -L 1 sed -i '' '1s/Control/CerbC9/'`. MacOS `sed` requires an argument after the `-i` option.

Comment: To optimize, change `grep` command line to `find . -type f`since `grep` will search 'Control' pattern for the whole huge file while in fact `sed` later will search again, hence the first search is redundant, leaving only `-r` option meaningful, that is `find` doing

Comment: `sed` seems to interpret a file name as a command script. What does `sed --version` show? Which OS do you use? **Please [edit] your question** to add information, **don't answer in comments**.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try something like

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/Control/CerbC9/g' {} +
```

or other methods suggested in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/112024/376404).